# What is the point of finally in a try catch/except finally statement

Tags: exception, finally

I have used try-catch/except-finally variants in many languages for years, today someone asked me what is the point of finally and I couldn't answer.

Basically why would you put a statement in finally instead of just putting it after the whole try-catch block? Or in other words is there a difference between the following blocks of code:

```
try{ //a}
catch {//b}
finally {//c}


try{//a}
catch{//b}
//c
```

EDIT:
PEOPLE, I know what finally does, I have been using it for ages, but my question is in the above example putting `//c` in finally seems redundant, doesn't it?

Answer (score 150, accepted):

The purpose of a `finally` block is to ensure that code gets run in three circumstances which would not very cleanly be handled using "catch" blocks alone:

1. If code within the `try` block exits via fallthrough or `return`

   If code within a `catch` block either rethrows the caught exception, or--accidentally or intentionally--ends up throwing a new one.

   If the code within the `try` block encounters an exception for which the `try` has no `catch`.

One could copy the `finally` code before every `return` or throw, and wrap `catch` blocks within their own try/catch to allow for the possibility of an accidental exception occurring, but it's far easier to forgo all that and simply use a `finally` block.

BTW, one thing I wish language designers would include would be an `exception` argument to the `finally` block, to deal with the case where one needs to clean up after an exception but still wants it to percolate up the call stack (e.g. one could wrap the code for a constructor in such a construct, and `Dispose` the object under construction if the constructor was going to exit with an exception).

Comment: We tried, you catched, and we finally have an answer to this question!

Comment: I think the key here was that it also executes even if there is a `return` statement within the `try/catch` statement. Without this understanding, a `finally` clause would seem quite trivial knowing that a `catch all` would essentially allow the code after the `try/catch` block to execute regardless of an exception. Thanks a lot, @supercat!

Comment: @Swivel: Both the return and the (typically re-) thrown exception within a catch cases are easier to handle with `finally` than without.

Comment: Sorry, but the third one is wrong. You can try a simple try and finally blocks in a Console application, Visual Studio 2019. Throw an exception in the try block, don't catch it, and the finally block will never be called...

Comment: @SItzik: Better now?

Comment: Where is the change?I'm affraid #3 is still wrong. Please try it. Open Visual Studio 2019, Console application, .Net framework 4.7 and write inside the main, A try and a finally blocks without catch. Throw an exception inside the try block, and tell if the finally block is being executed.

Comment: @SItzik: The change was stating that the `finally` block serves to handle the case where *the `try` block that contains it* doesn't catch the exception, and ensures that code which follows the `try` block or a call to a function containing it won't run until after the `finally` block executes.  If nothing which follows the `try` block or a call to the function containing it will ever be executed, that guarantee will be always be at least vacuously upheld whether or not the `finally` block executes.

Comment: I learned everything I wanted to know reading this, but the formatting of the "three circumstances" looks really janky to me. Given that #2 combines two different ways 'catch' can exit, why are the reasons for 'try' spread across #1 and #3? Also, a 'return' would also be relevant in catch but is not mentioned.

Comment: @Haighstrom: If a function opens a file, it's expected to do everything that needs to be done with the file and close it before it returns, and calling code is completely unaware of the fact that the function will be opening and closing the file, the file will need to be closed before the function exits, whether the function returns successfully or throws an exception.  Using a finally block is cleaner than duplicating the code within a "catch block" as well as on the non-exception path.

Comment: @Haighstrom: As for the scenario of a catch block exiting via return, I don't see that as creating an awkward scenario that wouldn't otherwise exist.  The point of `finally` is that it consolidates the cases that *can't* be nicely handled within `catch` blocks.

Answer (score 5):

To make it even easier to understand:

```
try{//a}
catch{//b}
//c
```

In above code, //c won't execute:

- if you use "return" inside the try block. **
- if you use "return" inside the catch block. **
- if you raise any exception inside the catch block.
- if your try block raises an exception that can't be caught by your catch block.

While in below code:

```
try{ //a}
catch {//b}
finally {//c}
```

//c will execute no matter what.

Comment: I like this answer much better than the accepted one. Clear and to the point: I can see exactly the reasons why/when finally is needed.

Answer (score 1):

`finally` is a syntactic sugar to allow DRY principle in `try-catch` pattern. Exception is usually thrown if the *library code* has not enough information to handle some state and wants the *client code* to solve it. If you don't have library-client code separation, you can handle everything by `if` instead of `try`.

Let's see a standard situation without `finally`:

```
void myFunction() {
  var r = allocateResources();
  r.doSomething();
  if(somethingBadHappens) {
    freeResources(r);
    throw new Exception(CODE42);
  }
  r.doSomethingMore();
  freeResources(r);
}
```

In the snippet above, you repeat `freeResources()`: this can be multiple statements which you need to repeat. This smells and `finally` block is the solution for clean code:

```
void myFunction() {
  var r = allocateResources();
  try {
    r.doSomething();
    if(somethingBadHappens) throw new Exception(CODE42);
    r.doSomethingMore();
  }
  finally {
    freeResources(r);
  }
  happyFunction();
}
```

Let's realize three levels of abstraction:

- **A1** is the library code providing `allocateResources()` function
- **A2** is our code providing `myFunction`, consuming A1
- **A3** is some client code consuming `myFunction` in try-catch block:

```
function A3code() {
  try {
    myFunction();
    doSomething();
  }
  catch(Exception e) {
    // no hanging resources here
    Console.WriteLine(e);
  }
}
```

Now let's see what can happen:

- if `allocateResources()` throws in A1, we don't know how to handle it in A2 (A2 code can be run in Console-free environment), so we delagate the situation to A3 without adding any further code. **If Exception is thrown here, the finally block is not executed**, since `finally` is bound to `try` which was not entered.
- if `somethingBadHappens` in try block, the stack unwinds to A3 where the situation is handled **BUT before it `finally` block is executed**, so we don't need to repeat it if no exceptions happen.
- before `finally` we can add `catch` block and try to resolve some potential exceptions from A1 which may appear in calling `r.doSomething` methods. Usually we want to handle exceptions as soon as possible to make the client code (A3) more comfortable for client coders.
- `happyFunction()` is executed only if nothing throws in `myFunction()` (inside or outside of `try` block).

As @supercat points out, the `finally` block is executed also if `try` block exits via return. I suggest you avoid this bad habit and have only one return in every function (maybe some early exists at the very beginning of functions). The reasons for single-return functions are:

1. The code is more readable: you look at the end and see WHAT the function returns. In multiple returns you must find all return occurences, inspect all the ifs, think about when the ifs are satisfied and only then you know what the function returns.
2. The code can be optimized by compilers, see [copy elision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision#Compiler_support).

The reason for multiple returns is avoiding many nested ifs, but there are other techniques to solve it. `Exception`s are exception in this rule.

Answer (score 0):

Finally block is executed even if an exception thrown in the try block. Therefore, for instance if you opened a stream before, you may want to close that stream either an exception is thrown or not. Finally block is useful for such an issue.

Comment: But you could also close the stream after the try-catch without a finally block.

Comment: That doesn't answer OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

Learn by example

```
let v = 0;
function f() {
    try {
        v = 1;
        return 2;
    } finally {
        v = 3;
        return 4;
    }
    v = 5;
    return 6;
}

const r = f();
console.log(r, v);
```

following prints "3, 4"

Answer (score -3):

`Finally` make sure your code is executed even if you get an exception.

*The finally block is useful for cleaning up any resources allocated in the try block as well as running any code that must execute even if there is an exception*

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwc8s4fz(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: but what is the difference between the two code blocks I mentioned? in both cases `//c` is executed, right?

Comment: @Ali - a finally block allows you to clean up any resources allocated and allow the excpetion to propogate back up the call stack if you are not handling the except locally.

Comment: in the second version //c would NOT be executed, if the code in //a called 'return' to exit the function. finally makes sure //c is called, even if the function is exited early. ... http://schwehr.org/blog/archives/2012-03.html#e2012-03-01T13_11_15.txt

Comment: @Ali I don't believe you understood the answer (or, I suspect, `finally`). Your edited clarification does not change the question.

Comment: Does not answer the actual question.